# New-Object cmdlet: How can I know is it the new process or it uses of existing ones?

Tags: powershell, outlook

PowerShell 4.0

I send the email through Outlook:

```
# Code sources:
# http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_function_send_email.htm
Function Global:Send-Email {
[cmdletbinding()]
Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=0)]
[String]$Address = "abcd@yandex.ru",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=1)]
[String]$Subject = "Hello!",
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]
[String]$Body = "Hello from PowerShell through Outlook."
      )
Begin {
Clear-Host
# Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
    }
Process {
# Create an instance Microsoft Outlook
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "$Address"
$Mail.Subject = $Subject
# $Mail.Body =$Body
$Mail.HTMLBody = "<b>When</b> is swimming?"
$File = "$env:HOMEDRIVE\Temp\1.txt"
$Mail.Attachments.Add($File)
$Mail.Send()
       } # End of Process section
End {
# Section to prevent error message in Outlook
$Outlook.Quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Outlook)
$Outlook = $null
   } # End of End section!
} # End of function

# Example of using this function
Send-Email #-Address deck@swimmingpool.com
```

This code either create new Outlook process (it such process is not exist still) or uses existing Outlook process. I want to close Outlook only if it wasn't working before. So, if Outlook was launched by user before my script begin to work, then I ought not to finish Outlook process. How can I know is the `$Outlook` use new process or it uses of existing Outlook process?

If I launch `Get-Command -Noun *object*` then I don't see something like `get-object` (for attempt at first to receive the existing object).

Comment: Would this just be a matter of checking for an existing process for Outlook with `Get-Process`? Possibly verifying the owner.

Comment: I thought about it but it is not the safe method (in my opinion), because it is possible that already exists the process with the same name but it will not be Outlook.

Comment: What do you mean by "wasn't working before"? Do you mean the process hanged and that is why you want to kill it?

Comment: I mean that if the `outlook` process was launched by user before will be launched my script, then `$Outlook.Quit()` finish the work of that process. But user don't expect such behaviour.